# Conditional expectation of function of two RVs, one previsible

Tags: probability-theory

**Setup:**
Let $(\epsilon_n)_{n\geq 1}$ be IID Bernoulli taking values in $\{-1,1\}$ and $\mathscr{F}_n=\sigma(\epsilon_1,\dotsc,\epsilon_n)$. Then let $(C_n)_{n\geq 1}$ be any previsible process (i.e. $C_n$ is $\mathscr{F}_{n-1}$ measurable) and $Z_0>0$ such that we may define the process $(Z_n)$ by $Z_n=Z_{n-1}+\epsilon_n C_n$ with $0<C_n<Z_{n-1}$ for $n\geq 1$.

**Specific question:**
How do I justify that if $Y_n=C_n/Z_{n-1}$ then
$\mathbb{E}(\log(1+\epsilon_n Y_n) | \mathscr{F}_{n-1})=g(Y_n)$ where $g(x)=p\log(1+x)+q\log(1-x)$ wherever this is defined?

**My thoughts:**
Intuitively, $Y_n$ would be known from $\mathscr{F}_{n-1}$ since $C_n$ is and so would $Z_{n-1}$ but I’ve been stumped from translating this into detail. I understand simpler calculations where you can “pull out what is known”, e.g. $\mathbb{E}(\epsilon_n C_n | \mathscr{F}_{n-1} )=C_n(2p-1)$ but here I directly know $C_n$ is previsible. It seems very natural to think “oh this RV is known so I can just average out the other one even when its a function of both” but I want to be sure why, especially when a function of the RVs is involved, if that’s true.

**Generalized a bit:**
More generally (but perhaps not totally well-posed), given some Borel function $f(x,y)$, and process $X, Y$ and $\mathscr{F}_n$ generated by $X$ when can one say
$\mathbb{E}(f(X_n, Y_n) | \mathscr{F}_{n-1})=g(Y_n)$ where $g(y)=\mathbb{E}(f(.,y))$? Is all that is needed that $Y_n$ is previsible? Or more? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For every sigma-algebra $\mathcal G$, every random variables $X$ and $Y$ and every measurable function $h$ such that $h(X,Y)$ is integrable, if $X$ is independent of $\mathcal G$ and $Y$ is $\sigma(\mathcal G)$-mesurable, then $$E(h(X,Y)\mid\mathcal G)=g(Y)$$ where the function $g$ is defined as $$g(y)=E(h(X,y))$$

*Proof:* It suffices to show that, for every bounded and $\sigma(\mathcal G)$-mesurable random variable $Z$, $$E(h(X,Y)Z)=E(g(Y)Z)$$ By hypothesis, $X$ is independent of $(Y,Z)$ hence, using Fubini, $$E(h(X,Y)Z)=\int\!\!\!\!\!\iint h(x,y)zdP_X(x)dP_{Y,Z}(y,z)=\iint\left(\int h(x,y)dP_X(x)\right)zdP_{Y,Z}(y,z)$$ Each inner parenthesis is $$\int h(x,y)dP_X(x)=E(h(X,y))=g(y)$$ hence the whole is $$E(h(X,Y)Z)=\iint g(y)zdP_{Y,Z}(y,z)=E(g(Y)Z)$$ and the proof is complete.