# When the Law of Iterated Expectation Works?

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation, conditional-probability

The Law of Iterated Expectations works for random variables $X$ and $Y$ as $E_{Y}[E[X|Y]] = E_X[X]$. 
However, if instead of $E[X|Y]$ we take $Var(X|Y)$, i.e. conditional variance, then we know that $E_{Y}[Var(X|Y)]$ $\neq$ $E_X[Var(X)]=Var(X)$. Consider an expression $f(X,Y)$, which is a general notation for $E[X|Y]$  or $Var(X|Y)$ or something else related to $X$ and $Y$.

The question is what conditions we have to impose on this expression $f(X,Y)$ and some other expression $g(X)$, for the following to be true ( or not to be true): $E_{Y}[f(X,Y)]=E_X[g(X)]$,  or may be  $E_{Y}[Pr[f(X,Y)<0|Y]]=Pr[f(X,Y)<0]$.
Thank you

Comment: There is indeed a law of total variance, by the way, https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_variance

Comment: Further check out this question’s answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3023233/291100 for something related to the latter half of the question. But there is something off here. First off how does one reconcile using $f$ to refer to both a single variable function $f(x)$ and a multi-variable one $f(x, y)$? One can find conditions (as explained in the link above) for $E(f(X, Y) | Y) =g(Y)$ where $g(y):=E(f(X,y))$ instead (the use of lowercase non-random $y$ and uppercase random $Y$ is *important*)

Comment: Thank you for the comments, the question is not about the law of total variance or similar, but about the nature of the expression f(X,Y) that makes the Law of Iterated Expectation works. The f(X,Y) is not assumed to be a function, it can be anything, e.g. Var(X|Y) or E(X|Y) or else. Does it make sense?

Comment: not really, sorry. I suggest reviewing the proofs of LTV and LTE to see why, in those specific cases, that one doesn’t collapse and one does but I don’t know if there is a general rule. By the way, the expression $E(P(f(X,Y) <0) | Y)$ is a little wonky. First off, $P(\cdot)$ is not a random variable—it is a probability ($P(\cdot | Y)$ is a RV, however, but that is a different story), and so the expectation is trivial ($=P(\cdot)$) even if you condition on $Y$. This is because, assuming $W=f(X,Y)$ is an RV then $P(W<0)$ is computed first, so the conditioning on $Y$ is superfluous.

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo, the probability is conditional as in $E_{Y}[Pr[f(X,Y)<0|Y]]$, so the $Pr[f(X,Y)<0|Y]$ is a random variable.

Comment: So the question can be formulated as: when $Pr[f(X,Y)<0]=E_{Y}[Pr[f(X,Y)<0|Y]]$ when we do not know in advance the exact nature of $f(X,Y)$

Comment: What is $E_Y[.]$? (And what is $E[.]$? What is the difference?

Comment: The expectation w.r.t. $Y$ and the expectation w.r.t. $X$. I have changed notations to make this meaning more explicit. Thank you for point this out.

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question correctly, but conditional expectation and conditional variance are both functions of $Y$. So, you have expectation of a function of $Y$ on the left hand side and an expectation of a different function of $X$ on the right hand side. Of course, you can find $g$ for any $f$ (provided the expectations are finite) such that the equality holds. Take $g(x)=x+\mathbb{E}[f(Y)]-\mathbb{E}[X]$.